# Getting "$digest already in progress" in async test with Jasmine 2.0

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, jasmine2.0

I know that calling `$digest` or `$apply` manually during a digest cycle will cause a "$digest already in progress" error but I have no idea why I am getting it here.

This is a unit test for a service that wraps `$http`, the service is simple enough, it just prevents making duplicate calls to the server while ensuring that code that attempts to do the calls still gets the data it expected.

```
angular.module('services')
    .factory('httpService', ['$http', function($http) {

        var pendingCalls = {};

        var createKey = function(url, data, method) {
            return method + url + JSON.stringify(data);
        };

        var send = function(url, data, method) {
            var key = createKey(url, data, method);
            if (pendingCalls[key]) {
                return pendingCalls[key];
            }
            var promise = $http({
                method: method,
                url: url,
                data: data
            });
            pendingCalls[key] = promise;
            promise.then(function() {
                delete pendingCalls[key];
            });
            return promise;
        };

        return {
            post: function(url, data) {
                return send(url, data, 'POST');
            },
            get: function(url, data) {
                return send(url, data, 'GET');
            },
            _delete: function(url, data) {
                return send(url, data, 'DELETE');
            }
        };
    }]);
```

The unit-test is also pretty straight forward, it uses `$httpBackend` to expect the request.

```
it('does GET requests', function(done) {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/some/random/url').respond('The response');

    service.get('/some/random/url').then(function(result) {
        expect(result.data).toEqual('The response');
        done();
    });
    $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

This blows up as sone as `done()` gets called with a "$digest already in progress" error. I've no idea why. I can solve this by wrapping `done()` in a timeout like this

```
setTimeout(function() { done() }, 1);
```

That means `done()` will get queued up and run after the $digest is done but while that solves my problem I want to know

- Why is Angular in a digest-cycle in the first place?
- Why does calling `done()` trigger this error?

I had the exact same test running green with Jasmine 1.3, this only happened after I upgraded to Jasmine 2.0 and rewrote the test to use the new async-syntax.

Comment: It's the new way to deal with async tests in Jasmine 2.0. It get's injected into the test-function and if you have not called it within 5 seconds the test fails. See https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Comment: There was no separate tag for jasmine 2.0, or I would have tagged it. I can see how the syntax is confusing if you've not seen it before.

Comment: OK, I spent nearly all day yesterday on this, but I do think I figured it out. I will add it as an answer, and I may be wrong.

Comment: @deitch that looks like some nice research, I'll see if I confirm what you found.

Comment: @ivarni please do, and post what you find.

Comment: @deitch I'm seeing the same you're seeing. Good job digging into this.

Comment: Glad I found this but sad that everyone is probably spending a day on this

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`$httpBacked.flush()` actually starts and completes a `$digest()` cycle. I spent all day yesterday digging into the source of ngResource and angular-mocks to get to the bottom of this, and still don't fully understand it.

As far as I can tell, the purpose of `$httpBackend.flush()` is to avoid the async structure above entirely. In other words, the syntax of `it('should do something',function(done){});` and `$httpBackend.flush()` do not play nicely together. The very *purpose* of `.flush()` is to push through the pending async callbacks and then return. It is like one big `done` wrapper around all of your async callbacks.

So if I understood correctly (and it works for me now) the correct method would be to remove the `done()` processor when using `$httpBackend.flush()`:

```
it('does GET requests', function() {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/some/random/url').respond('The response');

    service.get('/some/random/url').then(function(result) {
        expect(result.data).toEqual('The response');
    });
    $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

If you add console.log statements, you will find that all of the callbacks consistently happen during the `flush()` cycle:

```
it('does GET requests', function() {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/some/random/url').respond('The response');

    console.log("pre-get");
    service.get('/some/random/url').then(function(result) {
        console.log("async callback begin");
        expect(result.data).toEqual('The response');
        console.log("async callback end");
    });
    console.log("pre-flush");
    $httpBackend.flush();
    console.log("post-flush");
});
```

Then the output will be:

> pre-get
>
> pre-flush
>
> async callback begin
>
> async callback end
>
> post-flush

Every time. If you really want to see it, grab the scope and look at `scope.$$phase`

```
var scope;
beforeEach(function(){
    inject(function($rootScope){
        scope = $rootScope;
    });
});
it('does GET requests', function() {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/some/random/url').respond('The response');

    console.log("pre-get "+scope.$$phase);
    service.get('/some/random/url').then(function(result) {
        console.log("async callback begin "+scope.$$phase);
        expect(result.data).toEqual('The response');
        console.log("async callback end "+scope.$$phase);
    });
    console.log("pre-flush "+scope.$$phase);
    $httpBackend.flush();
    console.log("post-flush "+scope.$$phase);
});
```

And you will see the output:

> pre-get undefined
>
> pre-flush undefined
>
> async callback begin $digest
>
> async callback end $digest
>
> post-flush undefined

Comment: Yup, that seems to work and at least to me the explanation makes sense as well. Thanks!

Comment: If I could upvote this more than once I would. This saved me from digging through the source after banging my head on it all morning. Cheers!

Comment: Months later, and still you made my day. I am really glad all that work digging helped others.

Comment: Wow, this has been driving me crazy this afternoon. Once again, the angular docs let me down. Maybe the answer's in there, but it's not obvious. Thanks for a great answer!

Comment: @markrian excellent! Little bothers me more than 2 people doing the same work. I struggled through it, and now my efforts were helpful to you. That is a good day in my book.

Comment: What happens if you want to introduce a delay in $httpBackend? Then the expects will never get called. What will be the solution then?

Comment: @AdrianBer why? I think `$httpBackend.flush()` will still wait for everything to complete before returning. Unless I didn't understand how you want to introduce a delay?

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Comment: your answer saved me from going (more) insane. Thanks.

Comment: @ShaneRowatt I wish there were a "like" here. Your "more insane" was perfect!

Comment: Jesus H. Christ. Wasn't testing one of Angular's so called strong points? Testing should be easy... not this kind of need-to-know-internals shite. Thanks for the elaborate answer and clear explaining!

Comment: You are welcome. I banged my head on this last year. I still do some Angular, but when I need client-side, I have been leaning towards Aurelia for components or React for reactive. Just easier.

Answer (score 12):

@deitch is right, that `$httpBacked.flush()` triggers a digest. The problem is that when `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();` is run after each `it` is completed it also has a digest. So here's the sequence of events:

1. you call `flush()` which triggers a digest
2. the `then()` is executed
3. the `done()` is executed
4. `verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()` is run which triggers a digest, but you are already in one so you get an error.

`done()` is still important since we need to know that the 'expects' within the `then()` are even executed. If the `then` doesn't run then you might now know there were failures. The key is to make sure the digest is complete before firing the `done()`.

```
it('does GET requests', function(done) {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/some/random/url').respond('The response');

    service.get('/some/random/url').then(function(result) {
        expect(result.data).toEqual('The response');
        setTimeout(done, 0); // run the done() after the current $digest is complete.
    });
    $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

Putting `done()` in a timeout will make it executes immediately after the current digest is complete(). This will ensure that all of the `expects` that you wanted to run will actually run.

Comment: The `setTimeout` solution was what I was trying to avoid in the first place :)

Comment: You can put verifyNoOutstandingExpectation() in a timeout in your afterEach to make your 'it' cleaner instead.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @deitch's answer. To make the tests more robust you can add a spy before your callback. This should guarantee that your callback actually gets called.

```
it('does GET requests', function() {
  var callback = jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(function(result) {
    expect(result.data).toEqual('The response');
  });

  $httpBackend.expectGET('/some/random/url').respond('The response');
  service.get('/some/random/url').then(callback);
  $httpBackend.flush();

  expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```