# Testing AngularJS with Jasmine / Karma with $httpBackend not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, httpbackend

I'm trying to unit test my app built on Angular with Jasmine via Karma. The app involves making a call to the GitHub API and pulling the names of all the repos of a user and filling an array with those names. I'm trying to test that the array is getting filled but I'm having some issues with $httpBackend.

The relevant parts of my controller are:

```
readmeSearch.controller('ReadMeSearchController', ['RepoSearch', function(RepoSearch) {

  var self = this;
  self.gitRepoNames = [];

  self.doSearch = function() {
    var namesPromise =
      RepoSearch.query(self.username)
        .then(function(repoResponse) {
          addRepoNames(repoResponse);
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log('error: ' + error);
        });
    return namesPromise;
  };

  addRepoNames = function(response) {
    self.repoSearchResult = response.data;
    for(var i = 0; i < self.repoSearchResult.length; i++) {
      var name = self.repoSearchResult[i]['name']
      self.gitRepoNames.push(name);
    };
  };

}]);
```

My RepoSearch factory is:

```
readmeSearch.factory('RepoSearch', ['$http', function($http) {

  return {
    query: function(searchTerm) {
      return $http({
        url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + searchTerm + '/repos',
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          'access_token': gitAccessToken
        }
      });
    }
  };

}]);
```

And the test in question is this:

```
describe('ReadMeSearchController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('ReadMeter'));

  var ctrl;

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    ctrl = $controller('ReadMeSearchController');
  }));

  describe('when searching for a user\'s repos', function() {

    var httpBackend;

    beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend) {
      httpBackend = $httpBackend
      httpBackend
        .expectGET('https://api.github.com/users/hello/repos?access_token=' + gitAccessToken)
        .respond(
        { data: items }
      );
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
      httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
      httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    var items = [
      {
        "name": "test1"
      },
      {
        "name": "test2"
      }
    ];

    it('adds search results to array of repo names', function() {
      ctrl.username = 'hello';
      ctrl.doSearch();
      httpBackend.flush();
      expect(ctrl.gitRepoNames).toEqual(["test1", "test2"]);
    });

  });

});
```

When I run the test I get the error

> Expected [  ] to equal [ 'test1', 'test2' ].

So evidently this is because `self.gitRepoNames` is not being filled. When I console log `ctrl.repoSearchResult` just before the expectation in the test I get

```
Object{data: [Object{name: ...}, Object{name: ...}]}
```

Which is where the problem is I feel since `self.repoSearchResult.length` will be undefined when it is called in the for loop in the `addRepoNames` function.

So my question is why doesn't `response.data` return an array when it is called in the `addRepoNames` function in the test?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I should mention that the app works fine when run on the server.

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl.doSearch` is an asynchronous function. You should handle it in an [async way](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support). Try:

```
it('adds search results to array of repo names', function(done) {
  ctrl.username = 'hello';
  ctrl.doSearch().then(function() {
    expect(ctrl.gitRepoNames).toEqual(["test1", "test2"]);
    done();
  });
  httpBackend.flush();      
});
```

Comment: hi @yarons thanks for you reply. i've modified the test as per your response (with a `setTimeout` on `done()` as it was causing issues with `$digest`) but i'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: why `setTimeout`? what was the issue with `$digest`?

Comment: i was getting a `$digest already in progress`. from what i've read using `done()` and `httpBackend.flush()` together often causes issues. i referred to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341544/getting-digest-already-in-progress-in-async-test-with-jasmine-2-0)

Comment: I never had this problem. That's weird.